# Creating Dynamic model and store in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

I want to create dynamic model in Sencha from a xml file that contains the fields.Please tell me how to create a dynamic model and register it in app.js and if you can post Any sample application it would be a kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a store to read the fields form the xml file.
Then you can create a model with fields you loaded.
Last, create a store to read by the model.